# GCM and quickblox pushnotification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, chat, quickblox

I am having a trouble while subscribing to **Push notifications in quickblox** admin panel.
I have created session for subscribing to the quickblox pushnotification as well. As I have changed GCM API KEY many times but got the same error.
Please see below screenshot of log error.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Check Admin panel settings first  - set API key there

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android#Setup_GCM

2) to subscribe to pushes use **QBMessages.subscribeToPushNotificationsTask**

btw you can find ALL needed info here http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android